# How to fix TextField Binding <String> to show and edit in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding, textfield, option-type

I want to show text in `TextField` and able to edit it. But i'm having a problem while binding it. Here's my code:

```
struct DataView: View {
@ObservedObject private var dataPresenter = DataPresenter()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Name", text: $dataPresenter.data?.name ?? "") // This is the error

    }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            dataPresenter.getData()
        })
     }
}

class DataPresenter: ObservableObject {
@Injected private var getDataInteractor: GetDataInteractor
@Injected private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable>
@Published var data: GetDataResp?

func getData() {
    getDataInteractor.execute()
        .sink { error in
            print("Error:", error)
        } receiveValue: { response in
            if response.errorCode == "00" {
                print(response)
                self.data = response
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
     }
}

struct GetDataResp: Codable, Equatable {
     var name : String?
     var address : String?
     var email : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case address = "address"
        case email = "email"
     }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        address = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .address)
        email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)      
    }
}
```

When I'm not using `?` in `$dataPresenter.data.name ?? ""`, I always get an error like this:

[image]

Then, when I fix it with `?`, I get more errors like this:

[image]

I am stuck in this error cycle, using `force unwrap` will crash the app. I have more variables than just name, so I can't just `self.name = response.name ?? ""` inside the response. How I'm able to fix this?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextField` needs a `Binding`, not just a `String`. So, when you offer it `""` in the event that the `Binding` is nil, you end up with non-equivalent types (`Binding<String>` vs `String`).

To solve this, you'll probably need to create a custom binding that deals with the case of `data` being `nil`.

Here's one possible solution:

```
struct DataView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var dataPresenter = DataPresenter()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(dataPresenter.data?.name ?? "Empty")
            TextField("Name", text: dataPresenter.nonOptionalNameBinding())
        }
    }
}

struct GetDataResp {
    var name : String
}

class DataPresenter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: GetDataResp?
    
    func nonOptionalNameBinding() -> Binding<String> {
        .init {
            return self.data?.name ?? ""
        } set: { newValue in
            if self.data == nil {
                self.data = GetDataResp(name: newValue)
            } else {
                self.data?.name = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to handle the situation differently in the `set:` section based on your needs. And, of course, I stubbed out `GetDataResp`, which I'm assuming is more detailed than what I have there, but this should get you started.

---

Update, based on comments:

```
struct GetDataResp: Codable, Equatable {
     var name : String?
     var address : String?
     var email : String?
}

struct DataView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var dataPresenter = DataPresenter()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(dataPresenter.data?.name ?? "Empty")
            TextField("Name", text: dataPresenter.nonOptionalBinding(keyPath: \.name))
            TextField("Address", text: dataPresenter.nonOptionalBinding(keyPath: \.address))
            TextField("Email", text: dataPresenter.nonOptionalBinding(keyPath: \.email))
        }
    }
}


class DataPresenter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: GetDataResp?
    
    func nonOptionalBinding(keyPath: WritableKeyPath<GetDataResp,String?>) -> Binding<String> {
        .init {
            return self.data?[keyPath: keyPath] ?? ""
        } set: { newValue in
            if self.data == nil {
                self.data = GetDataResp()
            }
            self.data?[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still stuck here since in `GetDataResp` has respond like name, address, date, email, etc. I can't do `else` part. when I add a parameter, it can't assign because it's a let constant.
`func nonOptionalNameBinding(data: String?) -> Binding<String> {
        .init {
            return data ?? ""
        }
        set: { newValue in
            if self.dataMerchant == nil {
                print("empty", newValue)
            }
            else {
                data = newValue
            }
       }`
I wish I can use the parameter in `DataView` so I can create textfield as i want

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "I wish I can use the parameter in DataView so I can create textfield as I want". If you want to make it non optional, `GetDataResp` is going to have to be non-optional. But, if you keep it optional, you'll have to do something like this. If you include your code for `GetDataResp` (in your original question -- code in comments doesn't work well), I can try to show you how to use it.

Comment: hey man, just updated the `GetDataResp`, check my code. Thanks man

Comment: Doesn't look like it would change anything in my answer to me. I still don't know what the code in your comment is doing. For example, what is `dataMerchat`? It's never mentioned in your question.

Comment: Okay so, in your method, in `else` it's: `self.data?.name = newValue`. However, I have several other variables than just name such as address, email, etc. I mean the `self.data?.name = newValue` part is hardcoded when you use it in `DataView`. How do I assign the `self.data?.address = newValue` etc? Are you telling me to create 1 method for 1 variable?
Hopefully I can make you clear what I'm still struggling. 
Appreciated ur answer

Comment: Yes, you'd have to make a binding for an each one with this method. Again, the other way is to make `data` *not* optional. Then you'd have access to everything automatically. As it is, you have an uphill battle because your model *and* all of its properties are optionals, meaning you need to layers of shims for the optionals in order to get a non-optional binding. Let me see if I can come up with an example that'll work for you, but honestly, it would be good to change your architecture if you can.

Comment: Added a more generalized example for you using key paths so that you wouldn't have to create a binding for each one.

Comment: Hey man, thankyou very much for ur time & effort, it works.
But i still curious with the other option to make `data` not optional, cause if I do `var data: GetDataResp` I get `Class 'DataPresenter' has no initializers.` Or did you mean changing the `name`, `address` etc to `: String` ?

Comment: If you make `data` non-optional, you'd have to provide a value, whether through an initializer ur just doing `var data = GetDataResp()`. You'd still need a layer of custom binding for the `String?`s unless you *also* made them non-optional